# Replace Specific field values in fabric

Tags: python, fabric

i have file with below content i want to change only some values in below code.how can i do it in fabric.

```
 totem {
 version: 2
 cluster_name: lbcluster
 transport: udpu
 interface {
 ringnumber: 0
 bindnetaddr: server_private_IP_address
 broadcast: yes
 mcastport: 5405
 }
}

 quorum {
 provider: corosync_votequorum
 two_node: 1
}

 nodelist {
 node {
 ring0_addr: primary_private_IP_address
 name: primary
 nodeid: 1
}
 node {
 ring0_addr: secondary_private_IP_address
 name: secondary
 nodeid: 2
}
}

 logging {
 to_logfile: yes
 logfile: /var/log/corosync/corosync.log
 to_syslog: yes
 timestamp: on
}
```

I want to Change only "secondary_private_IP_address" & " primary_private_IP_address" & "server_private_IP_address" values from this  file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed, an example:

```
def sed_ip():
    sed('/home/user/test/file', 'primary_private_IP_address', '192.168.0.0')
```